# hide Woocommerce price suffix on category page

Tags: php, woocommerce

I'm using a custom code to modify my price suffix, so i'm not displaying it via the woocommerce setting, I'm using this code in my function.php to get the price suffix on product pages.

```
    function change_product_price_html($price){

    $newPrice   .= $price;
    $newPrice   .= " <span class=\"woocommerce-price-suffix\">inkl. MwSt., <a href='https://www.amaoni.de/zahlung-versand#versandkosten'>zzgl. Versandkosten</a></span>";

    return $newPrice;
}
```

But now it's also showing the price suffix on category pages.

I found this solution, which didn't work for me.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'hide_price_on_shop');

function hide_price_on_shop($price){
    if(is_shop()){
        $price = '';
    }
    return $price;
}
```

is there a way to have the price suffix only at the product pages and not on the category pages?

[image: Category Page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you  want this to show *only* on the product page, you could override the woocommerce/single-product/price.php file in your theme.

To do this; simply copy plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/price.php to yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product/price.php.

Then in your new price.php file, you can have something like:

**price.php**

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
   exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

global $product;
?>

<p class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_price_class', 'price' ) );?>">
    <?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?>
    <span class=\"woocommerce-price-suffix\">inkl. MwSt., <a href='https://www.amaoni.de/zahlung-versand#versandkosten'>zzgl. Versandkosten</a></span>
</p>
```