# Woocommerce: Show Price Suffix only on Product Page

Tags: php, css, woocommerce

I added the following code to "My Custom Functions PHP Inserter" plugin to show a custom price suffix in my woocommerce shop.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_suffix', 100, 2 );

function custom_price_suffix( $price, $product ){
    $price = $price . ' inkl. MwSt. und <a href="http://www.link.to/shippinginfo">zzgl. Versandkosten</a>'; 
    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_price', $price );
}
```

It works, but it also shows the price on the product category page and shop page. How can I avoid that?

I tried this css code but doesn't work:

```css
.woocommerce-price-suffix {
      display: none;
    }
    .single-product .product-price-wrap .woocommerce-price-suffix {
      display: block !important;
    }
```

The following solution might work, but I don't want to overwrite a php file in my theme: [hide Woocommerce price suffix on category page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54831405/hide-woocommerce-price-suffix-on-category-page)

I also want to change the font size of "inkl. MwSt. und zzgl. Versandkosten", but I don't know how to do this in php. Tried this css but doesn't do anything:

```css
.custom_price_suffix {
  font-size: small;
}
```

Comment: Show me the live page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in [`is_singular()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_singular/) function to check if you are on a singular product page

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_suffix', 100, 2 );
function custom_price_suffix( $price, $product ) {
    if(is_singular('product')) {
        $price = $price . ' inkl. MwSt. und <a href="http://www.link.to/shippinginfo">zzgl. Versandkosten</a>'; 
    }
    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_price', $price );
}
```

If you want to change the size - you can simply wrap your text inside a span and add CSS to it - i.e. change your $price variable to this:

```
$price = $price . ' <span class="make-me-small">inkl. MwSt. und <a href="http://www.link.to/shippinginfo">zzgl. Versandkosten</a></span>';
```

and then add the following to your CSS:

```
.make-me-small {
    font-size: 0.8rem;
}
```

---

## Edit: Adding location specific adjustment

As per your comment regarding adjustment of the link text based on the base language of the website, there are two ways to achieve this:

**The first route** (and probably the best/accepted way) is to use the built in string translation management functions. You can do this by using the [`__()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__/) function and wrapping it around your text like this:

```
$price = $price . __(' inkl. MwSt. und <a href="http://www.link.to/shippinginfo">zzgl. Versandkosten</a>', 'my-text-domain');
```

Once you've done that, you will see that your text will now show up under your *String Translations* tab under the WPML menu item on your dashboard - from there you can manually assign it a new string(s) based on the different site languages.

**The second route** is to manually add the adjustment inside the function using a `switch` (or `if` statement) statement:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_suffix', 100, 2 );
function custom_price_suffix( $price, $product ) {
    if(is_singular('product')) {
        $language_code = apply_filters( 'wpml_current_language', NULL );
        switch ($language_code) {
            case 'de':
                $suffix = ' inkl. MwSt. und <a href="http://www.link.to/shippinginfo">zzgl. Versandkosten</a>';
                break;

            case 'it':
                $suffix = ' IVA e spese di <a href="http://www.link.to/shippinginfo">spedizione incluse</a>';
                break;

            default:
                $suffix = ' incl. VAT and <a href="http://www.link.to/shippinginfo">shipping costs</a>';
                break;
        }
        $price = $price . $suffix; 
    }
    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_price', $price );
}
```

Comment: there seems to be a mistake in your code with the { brackets

Comment: Ah - thanks for spotting that @Andy! Fixed it up now.

Comment: Thank's for the quick fix. It does work, kinda...But now the price is removed from the product categroy page and shop page. I only wanted to remove the price suffix from those two pages and only display the price suffix on the single product page.

Comment: ...Meaning: on the shop page and product category page it should show only the price and on the single product page it should show the price + price suffix @Frits

Comment: @Andy ah - yeah, I had the `return` in the wrong place - I've edited the answer to fix it up for you :)

Comment: Now it works, Thank you so much!! Do you have any idea how I can display a different price suffix for different languages? I am using WPML for language translation. WPML uses this constant "ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE". I need to implement `if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == "de")` and `if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == "it")` to display a different price suffix based on the language selected.

Comment: @Andy that's awesome! I'm glad to have helped - would you mind upvoting and accepting the answer? (it's the big tick under the voting buttons - it would really help) - regarding the wpml part - sure, just give me a few minutes to edit the answer for you :)

Comment: Thank's for helping me!! I updated the code but it gives me WSOD again...
Also I don't know where to add the span class to change the font size via CSS. Aaaaand I just found out that ICL_Language_Code is outdated and should be replaced with this hook: [link](https://wpml.org/wpml-hook/wpml_current_language/)

Comment: It works now :) It should be 'my-text-domain' and not 'my-text-domain` (see the final apostrophe thing) 
so the code that works for me is: 
`add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_suffix', 100, 2 );
function custom_price_suffix( $price, $product ) {
    if(is_singular('product')) {
        $price = $price . __(' <span class="make-me-small">inkl. MwSt. und <a href="http://www.link.to/shippinginfo">zzgl. Versandkosten</a></span>', 'my-text-domain'); 
    }
    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_price', $price );
}`
Big big thanks to @Frits for helping me!!

Comment: @Andy awesome - well spotted. I've fixed the apostrophe :) If you want, I've also adjusted the language function to use the latest hook you mentioned. Cheers :)

Comment: You're awesome! Thank you so much @Frits :)

Comment: @Frits Awesome code, but how do you hide the suffix in the price shown in the related products? Thanks

Comment: @KoolPal that would depend entirely on whether you are using the first or the second route mentioned in the answer - either way, I would suggest creating a new question with your exact situation for a faster result :) Feel free to link your new question in the comments here when you are done and I will go have a look :)

Comment: @Frits I have asked a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60462833/8044005 Please review and guide me. Thanks